# Syntax error in Python/pygame

Tags: python, pygame, init

I'm just learning python/pygame and I'm doing a physics tutorial. Unfortunately, I think it was made in an older version of python. I copied the code in the video exactly, but when I run it it returns "Failed to run script - syntax error - invalid syntax(physics.py, line 7)". I'm sure it's just something stupid and obvious that I'm missing, but any answer would go a long way for me!

```
import os, sys, math, pygame, pygame.mixer
from pygame.locals import *

screen_size = screen_width, screen_height = 600, 400

class MyCircle:
    def __init__(self, (x, y), size, color = (255,255,255), width = 1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.width = width

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.size, self.width)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

my_circle = MyCircle((100,100), 10, red)
my_circle_2 = MyCircle((200,200), 30, blue)
my_circle_3 = MyCircle((300,150), 40, green, 4)
my_circle_4 = MyCircle((450,250), 120, black, 0)

fps_limit = 60
run_me = True
while run_me:
    clock.tick(fps_limit)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run_me = False

    my_circle.display()
    my_circle_2.display()
    my_circle_3.display()
    my_circle_4.display()

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you think the problem is related to your python version, what version of python are you using?

Comment: As a side note, what tutorial is this? For example, the code is clearly for something in the 2.3-2.7 range, which means it's intentionally defining `MyCircle` as a classic class. Also, there is no good reason for the tuple parameter unpacking that's causing your problems. And the `while run_me` is a silly attempt to avoid `break` because someone heard it was bad back when he was programming C. This is fine as a quick sample to slap on a wiki, but as a tutorial, it's not something I'd trust.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Python 3. Tuple parameter unpacking was removed in 3.X, so you have to change this:

```
def __init__(self, (x, y), size, color = (255,255,255), width = 1):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.size = size
    self.color = color
    self.width = width
```

To:

```
def __init__(self, position, size, color = (255,255,255), width = 1):
    self.x, self.y = position
    self.size = size
    self.color = color
    self.width = width
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, line 7 is this line:

```
def __init__(self, (x, y), size, color = (255,255,255), width = 1):
```

See that `(x, y)` in the middle of the parameter list? This is a feature called "tuple parameter unpacking", and it was removed in Python 3.0. (It's also discouraged in Python 2.6-2.7, but it works, so some people still use it.)

[PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) has the full details.

If you run the `2to3` tool on your script, it'll tell you how to fix it.

But the simple fix is to replace that tuple `(x, y)` with a single parameter `xy`, and split it inside the function:

```
def __init__(self, xy, size, color = (255,255,255), width = 1):
    self.x, self.y = xy
    self.size = size
    self.color = color
    self.width = width
```